# How to understand "it is" in "what it is he is trying to express"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

"His writing is so confusing that it’s difficult to make out what **it is** he is trying to express."

How to understand "it is" in "what it is he is trying to express"? Does "he is trying to express" a relative clause to modify "it"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the source of that sentence? Any link?

Answer (score 3):

> ... what **it is** he is trying to express.

Syntactically this is a moderately complicated clause. Among its features are

1. **an omitted relative pronoun** (relativizer)
   The full form of the final clause would be

   > ***that*** he is trying to express.

   It is very common to omit a relativizer which acts as the object of the verb, as happens here

   > <s>that</s><sub>1</sub> he is trying to express _<sub>1</sub>.

   Keep an eye on that subscript <sub>1</sub> after the deleted *that* and the ‘trace’ (notated with an underscore, _) which marks the ‘canonical’ position of the constituent which it replaces. The subscript is an ‘index’ which signifies that the two terms have the same referent. *He* is trying to express ‘something’—that ‘something’ is referred to by *that*.

   This relative clause is embedded in
2. **an *it* cleft**
   This is an ‘information packaging’ construction which focuses one constituent of a canonical clause by making it the complement of *it BE* and subordinating what is left as a relative clause.

   > John loves Mary. *If we want to focus* Mary *we make it the object of* It is *and relativize* John loves ...
   >   It is Mary whom John loves.

   Experts disagree about the precise status of *It* here. Some regard it as an *expletive* (‘dummy’) pronoun which has no actual referent; others regard it as an ordinary pronoun whose referent is the complement, thus:

   > It<sub>1</sub> is Mary<sub>1</sub> whom John loves.

   In any case, that’s where your ***it is*** comes from:

   > **it<sub>1</sub> is** _<sub>1</sub> <s>that</s><sub>1</sub> he is trying to express _<sub>1</sub>.

   “But wait!” I hear you protest. “What is the complement of *is*? What’s that trace there where the complement ought to be?” ... The complement has been replaced by the operation of a third feature—
3. **a free relative clause**
   This is a construction which permits us to treat a ‘specified’but ‘indefinite’ constituent of a clause as a syntactic NP. We replace the constituent with an interrogative/relative *wh-* word and move that to the head of the clause:

   > **what**<sub>1</sub> it is _<sub>1</sub> ...

   This construction stands as the direct object of the preposition verb (phrasal verb) *make out*:

   > ... to make out **what**<sub>1</sub> it<sub>1</sub> is _<sub>1</sub> <s>that</s><sub>1</sub> he is trying to express _<sub>1</sub>.

In the end, all the references converge on the single term *what*.

If you’ve followed all this you may now be wondering what purpose the *it* cleft serves. Wouldn’t it be simpler to write this?

> to make out what he is trying to express.<sup>†</sup>

The answer, I think, is that the *it* cleft is introduced for rhetorical purposes. The simplified version asks, in effect, “What is he trying to express?” The version with the *it* cleft, particularly with the relativizer omitted, throws the prosodic emphasis onto *is*, which produces a stronger sense of puzzlement—and perhaps exasperation, too.

> difficult to make out what it ***is*** ...

---

<sup>†</sup> A point that MaulikV has acutely brought up even as I was writing this.

Comment: What an excellent answer! A bit more (on *"It's raining"*, etc.) and we'd have the "canonical it" answer here! I'm not sure it's "acute" to say the "it cleft" is superfluous. As you indicate yourself, it introduces nuances not intrinsically present in the shorter version. If "superfluous" means *not [grammatically] required* then okay - but not if it implies *semantically useless padding which should never be present*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly: it is 'packaging' which adapts the bare content to some specific context.

Comment: Or as you might have said, *"That's exactly it!"*. Within which context **it** doesn't get us much further to point out that "syntactically", **that = it** and **it = that**. I hadn't registered the term **it-cleft** before, but it sure looks useful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's also called just *cleft* - that's what you'll find in McCawley. I always say *it-cleft* because I can never remember whether it is this or the *wh-cleft* which is called a *pseudo-cleft*.

Comment: Wow! Wikipedia lists *seven* distinct types of "cleft" construction, among which is the charmingly-named [**Reversed wh-cleft/Inverted pseudo-cleft**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence), for which they offer *A Fiat is what he wanted to buy* as an example. Just give me money. That's what I want (as Lennon-McCartney would have it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, it's fun; but I tend to forget taxonomic specifications longer than the entities they describe. I had a question yesterday that involved what CGEL calls “number transparent quantificational nouns”, e.g. *lots*.

Answer (score 1):

> [His writing is so confusing] [that] [it is difficult to make out what it is] [he is trying to express]

I think the words *it* and *is* are superfluous in this sentence. Without them too, the sentence makes sense and conveys the message.

> "His writing is so confusing that it’s difficult to make out what  *<del>it is</del>* he is trying to express."